# updating timer on collision

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Hi guys can anyone help me on how I would code a timer update which increases on colliding with a specific object using corona sdk and LUA.

Basically a timer will countdown and if a player collides with a star then the timer should go + 5 etc.

heres my timer set up

```
function timerDown()
  timeLimit = timeLimit-1
  timeLeft.text = timeLimit
```

And the star

```
star = display.newImage("star1.png")
  star.name = "star"
  star.x = 700
  star.y = 200
  physics.addBody(star, "static")
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: From [Corona labs API documentation](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/physics/addBody.html) on `physics.addBody()` **NOTE: This API should not be used in a Collision Event handler.**

Comment: What is the right way it should be done? im new to corona and LUA.

Answer (score 0):

```
local timeLimit

function timerDown()
  timeLimit = timeLimit-1
  timeLeft.text = timeLimit
end

function newFunc( event )
  if event.phase == "began" then
     timeLimit = timeLimit + 5
  end
end

star = display.newImage("star1.png")
  star.name = "star"
  star.x = 700
  star.y = 200
  physics.addBody(star, "static")
  star:addEventListener( "collision", newFunc )

timer.performWithDelay( 1000, function() timerDown() end, timeLimit )
```

This will help you to start. Depending on your objects, you may need some modifications on collision listener.

Comment: It seems that when I use the code above the timer just stalls at 5 seconds left. It all updates fine and works perfect upon collision  except for this stalling part. What is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that, timeLimit, timerDown() and newFunc() are in same module?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, im sorry but i am very new to coding and starting to grasp it. Do they all need to be within a same function to work?

Comment: You have a project file, and in that file you have some .lua files right? And you "activate" them by typing "require( something.lua )". So each of those files are called modules. 
I just mean that those timeLİmit, timerDown() and newFunc() must be in same scope. With doing so, they can see/recognize each other.